# copy view to create an exact replica of a view. Move the view relative to the screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-view

As the title already indicates, I am not pretty sure what to search for getting help for my question. I've googled many different combinations of what I think would be the right terms, but till now it seems that I am not naming the things right.

Currently I am trying to accomplish following.
This is how it should work:

I have a scrollView with different views in it. Each time the user clicks on such a view, the view should be brought to the front, moved to the top of the screen independent of the scrollposition of the scrollView and finally expand to a new view.

I've also made an example of what it could look like. Actually I am trying to expand it to fullscreen.
[image: animated example of the problem]

I'm not sure whether I have to create a new activity, new fragment or view in my case. I know that this will be easier in Android L, but I wanted to find out a way of doing this in 4.0 - 4.4 too. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package com.example.anotherviewaddtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear);
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++){ //create a scrollview
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv.setText("t\ne\nx\nt\nV\nie\nw "+Integer.toString(i));
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN+10000*i);
            tv.setOnClickListener((new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v){                    
                    func(v);
                }
               }));
            layout.addView(tv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void func(View toAdd){

// values for animation x_start
            int toAdd_top=toAdd.getTop();

        ViewGroup root=(ViewGroup) toAdd.getRootView();

//remove view from scrollview       
        ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)toAdd.getParent();
        ScrollView itsParent=(ScrollView)parent.getParent();
        parent.removeView(toAdd);
     // animation values x_start, x_end and y_end

int scrolledAmount=itsParent.getScrollY();      
            int margin=itsParent.getTop();
            int scrollView_left=itsParent.getLeft();
            int scrollView_top=itsParent.getTop();
            if(scrolledAmount==0) // fix for first element selected
                scrolledAmount=-scrollView_top;


//gets the main layout of the app and adds the removed to it. Traverse down along your own decor view if it is different . In this example i have decorView->LinearLayout(child at 0)->FrameLayout (child at 1)->main layout of app(child at 0) 
        ViewGroup base=(ViewGroup) ((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)root.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0);
        base.addView(toAdd);


//  set the animation   
        TranslateAnimation ani= new TranslateAnimation(scrollView_left,scrollView_left,-scrolledAmount,-(toAdd_top-margin));
        ani.setDuration(1000);
        toAdd.startAnimation(ani);
//listener to call new activity at end of animation
        ani.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim){
                //start new Activity here
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}
            ;});
// removes the view that was added to main layout
        base.removeView(toAdd);
    }
    }
```

Here's an even simpler way of doing that . This takes the view, adds it to main layout at 0,0 then animation starts with values that you will have to find out as per you need. In this example, which has only scrollview, the view translates from its position on screen to top of scrollview. Maybe you can do this in even simpler way by just setting the animation on with proper values and simply removing the view from the scroll layout but i havent tried that yet

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint! I think from this time I can reach the next steps. I'm still wondering what to google for to find similar results.... sigh...

Comment: Oh check back here tomorrow, i will add comments :-) am slightly occupued rn